# Why was my duplicate and deleted post reopened and undeleted?

Tags: discussion, closing, deleted-questions, closed-questions, undeletion

[My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3883276/717872) was correctly closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33215/717872).

I deleted the question after it was closed, but 7 hours after (13 minutes ago at the time of writing), the post was reopened and undeleted by the moderator [Alexander Gruber ♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12952/alexander-gruber). Why?

[image: revisions]

[Revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3883276/revisions)

Comment: I suppose that self-deleting may be your choice in many circumstances, but it is often considered that keeping (not deleting) a certain number of closed-as-duplicates is beneficial for the site.

Comment: @hardmath  Save for the fact that PEDMAS/BEMDAS questions have on overwhelming number of duplicates.  And that many of them, just like the one asked by this user, don't remember that division and multiplication have equal precedence, and should be performed left to right, and that addition and subtraction have equal precedence, and should be performed from left to right, after operations with higher precedence have been performed.  PE(M=D)(A=S)

Comment: $4\div 2 + 2\times 3 -5 = 2 + 6 - 5 = 8-5= 3$

Comment: And somehow, it now has two votes to close as "Missing context." No idea what those people were thinking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because it was flagged that the duplicate was inappropriate-- specifically, that the duplicate target was about implicit parenthesis, which was not applicable to your question.

I do think this is a good point, so I reopened it. I expect it will be closed again, most likely, but with a more appropriate duplicate target.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966916/is-9-41-not-equal-to-4 might be a good target (though it's closed), or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936016/does-3-41-equal-0-or-2-or-maybe-2.

Comment: Why undelete it, though?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo some actions can't be performed on self-deleted posts, e.g. editing by self. This can lead to undeleting simply in order to copy out MathJax etc. when recycling content, before deleting again.